# How to solve error ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined) in tortoiseGit?

Tags: github, tortoisegit, github-issues

[image]
**Error Details:**

```
[git.exe push --progress "origin" main:main
Enumerating objects: 128, done.
Counting objects: 100% (128/128), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (100/100), done.
Writing objects: 100% (110/110), 158.47 MiB | 1.88 MiB/s, done.
Total 110 (delta 34), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (34/34), completed with 8 local objects.
remote: error: Trace: 7bb86f7cc5c0d39363c909d35194c3f8241396d6eeead4323992b97257ec847e
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File pdfGenerationFromHtmlRazor/DinkToPDF.zip is 113.39 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To github.com:NakibBracu/.Net-Practise-DEVSkill.git
! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:NakibBracu/.Net-Practise-DEVSkill.git']
```

I want to know how to solve this with tortoise git only. If I have a file size larger than 100mb and mistakenly committed the file. Then how to solve this for tracing the large file and select specifically to ignore this. Cause I committed and push in the other sub directories already and that's cause problem.

Answer (score 0):

The file name of the too large file is included in the error message.

Now open the log on that file to find the commit where it got added.

Then open the log of the whole repository (e.g., by selecting whole project in the lower left).

Click on the previous commit and select rebase on this. In the rebase dialog edit the commit in question. When the rebase stops, select edit commit at the bottom, select continue and deselect the large file. Finish the rebase. Done.